# Почему при использовании redux в методе componentWillReceiveProps nextProps всегда равны this.props, хотя свойства добавляються?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Почему при использовании redux в методе componentWillReceiveProps nextProps всегда равны this.props, хотя свойства добавляються ?